# Error 403 and XAMPP Error 20024

Tags: xampp, http-status-code-403

So I have looked at many places to try and find the answer to this but could really use some other ideas for possibly how to fix this. I have gone into the new XAMPP security concept and change the Deny to Allow

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-     status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Above is what my httpd-xampp.conf looks like at the bottom. I still am getting the 403 error on the website when I go to the localhost. So I then looked to the error log and found I am getting this error.

```
[Fri Oct 26 08:58:29.731458 2012] [core:error] [pid 5096:tid 1680] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:59590] AH00127: Cannot map GET /system/%3C?echo($template. HTTP/1.1 to file
```

I have no idea what this means but I am running out of options. If anyone could help me or has an idea as to what might be giving me this error. I will try anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so it turns out the problem is with XAMPP. Not sure why but when I tested this on another dev server everything worked just fine. I am guessing it has something to do with the new XAMPP Security Concept. My best answer to this would be to change the Deny to Allow in that section of your httpd-xampp.conf file. This solution worked for many people except me.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly due to [Apache bug 41441](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441). The Apache coders don't call it a bug and have closed it as WONTFIX in end of 2009. However, I am also experiencing this error on heidisql.com where I get tons of misformatted requests from spammers, harvesters and other broken clients. My error log is full of these, and I would be glad to have a way to handle such requests with a redirect or rewriterule.

Your URL does not contain a colon (:)

> /system/%3C?echo($template.

... but %3C translates to "<", which is also used in Windows filesystem paths, which is why Apache is blocking that request for security reasons.